# UISearchBar's text move to bottom when input content?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I customized a **UISearchbar**, the code is like this:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UIView {

lazy var searchBar: MySearchBar = {
    let search = MySearchBar()
    search.tintColor = UIColor.orange
    search.barTintColor = UIColor.yellow
    search.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    search.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0)
    return search
}()
lazy var cancelButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("取消", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    return button
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupUI()
    setupConstraints()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setupUI() {
    addSubview(searchBar)
    addSubview(cancelButton)
}

private func setupConstraints() {
    searchBar.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(6)
        make.height.equalTo(32)
        make.width.equalToSuperview().offset(-80)
    }
    cancelButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(searchBar.snp.right).offset(13)
        make.centerY.equalTo(searchBar)
    }
}
}

class MySearchBar: UISearchBar {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() -> Int! {
    var index: Int!
    let searchBarView = subviews[0]
    for (i, view) in searchBarView.subviews.enumerated() {
        if view.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
            index = i
            break
        }
    }
    return index
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let index = indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() {
        let searchField: UITextField = subviews[0].subviews[index] as! UITextField
        searchField.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Search_icon"))
        searchField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        searchField.borderStyle = .none
        searchField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        searchField.backgroundColor = barTintColor
        searchField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        searchField.placeholder = "input something"
    }
 }
}
```

we can see that it is very simple. Just added a **searchBar** and **cancelButton**.
Then I added it to **navigationBar** as **subView**, make it becomeFirstResponder in viewController.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
   lazy var customeSearchBar = CustomSearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(customeSearchBar)
    customeSearchBar.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(44)
    }
    customeSearchBar.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
```

}

At first, I input content is ok.

[image]

When I continue input content, then the issue shows up:

[image]

It looks like the content move to the bottom. I tried to find something to fix the problem. But I didn't get it. 
It is a strange thing that works fine in simulate and some iPhone. But one of my phone works wrong.

Comment: can u pls share the project?

Comment: ok, How can I send it to you?

Comment: Share ur dropbox link

Comment: This is the demo : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yuvufd3lus80oh/Demo.zip?dl=0. Thanks

Comment: I saw ur code. It is not coming at the beginning itself

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When u continuously type something, the language is changed. Is that the issue?

Comment: I don't think so, I still try to figure out. Thanks

Comment: Then what is the exact issue?

Comment: We can see the images, the text just moves to bottom, not in the center. That's the problem.